# Subscribing to an individual bug on debbugs

Tags: emacs-development

Is it possible to subscribe to an individual bug on https://debbugs.gnu.org/?

By subscribe, I mean that ideally one would receive all the e-mails sent to that bug report, but something like an RSS or Atom feed would also be useful.

I'm aware that one can subscribe to `bug-gnu-emacs`, and filter client-side (e.g. for something like "to `N@debbugs.gnu.org`" or "cc `N@debbugs.gnu.org`"), but that doesn't seem ideal.

Googling, I've found this bug report:

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=5439

which suggests that per-bug subscribing is not possible, but perhaps something might have changed since 2010.

Comment: Bug #5439 is still in "wishlist" status. It is still open.

Comment: True. However, it's possible that the issue had been "fixed", but the bug report itself simply forgotten about — considering the number of all the bugs on debbugs it didn't seem that implausible. (OTOH, looking now, there are only [a couple of open bugs against debbugs.gnu.org itself](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/pkgreport.cgi?package=debbugs.gnu.org), so it is indeed unlikely.)

Comment: Yes, you're right that it often happens that a bug report is ignored/forgotten and the bug gets fixed at some point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Every bug has a webpage, so if there is no other way then you can use a change notification service which sends you a mail when the page changes.

Or if you know elisp then you could even write a simple emacs script which runs a timer in the background fetching the page reglularly and notifies you if the content changes.